# How many non-equivalent configuration of $2 \times 2 \times 2$ Rubik cubes with $6$ distinct colors?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles, polya-counting-theory

> How many non-equivalent configuration of $2\times2\times2$ Rubik cube with $6$ distinct colors are there?

You can also think this question such a way that how many non-equivalent colorings  are there  to color $24$ square on a cube whose each faces have $4$ squares.

**My try:** At first glance, I thought that I can solve it using Polya theorem such that if we call the colors as $a,b,c,d,e,f$, then find $[a^4b^4c^4d^4e^4f^4]$ in the statement constructed by Burdsides' lemma and Polya theorem.

Then, the cumbersome part is to find the statement. Firstly, I assumed that the cube has $24$ symmetries as expected. So, I found the following:

- $\pi_0=x_1^{24}$, the identity permutation
- $\pi_1=\pi_3 =x_4^6$, the $90^\circ$ and $270^\circ$ rotations
- $\pi_2=x_2^{12}$, the $180^\circ$ rotations.

We have three times these rotations, so $3\times (\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3)=6x_4^6+3x_2^{12}$:

- **For opposite middle points:** $6 (x_2^{12})$
- **Diagonal $120^\circ$:** $x_3^8$
- **Diagonal $240^\circ$:** $x_3^8$

So, $4 \times 2x_3^8=8x_3^8$ for diagonal rotations.

**RESULT:** $$\frac{1}{24}[x_1^{24}+9x_2^{12}+8x_3^8 +6x_4^6]$$

$\color{red}{\text{However,}}$ this is not a cube, it is a Rubik cube, so I understood that I have more symmetry than $24$ such that I can also rotate the blocks each consisting of $4$ subcubes, or I can rotate two blocks at the same time. Hence, I have more symmetry.

Related links:

- https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-calculate-the-number-of-permutations-of-a-2x2x2-Rubik%E2%80%99s-cube-Can-you-clearly-explain-how

I want help to solve this question using Polya's technique. Can you help me to find all symmetries and writing correct Polya formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (The name of the inventor was "Rubik", not "rubic".)

Comment: IIRC the symmetry group of a $2\times2\times2$ Rubik's cube is $C_2^7\rtimes S_8$, so I'm not sure if this can be done by hand.

Comment: Your first sentence reframing the problem is incorrect.  Not only are there exactly 4 squares of each color, but to be a valid configuration, it has to be solvable, which means, for example, that only one corner can have red, blue, and green on it.  There are further restrictions coming from the fact that some configurations reachable by disassembling and reassembling the cube are not reachable through valid moves.  So you should be very clear on what it is and what it is not that you want to enumerate.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A075152 and references therein might be helpful.

Comment: @runway44 can you provide a link or source for the symmetry group ?

Comment: @Aaron yeah  ,you are right , i read your comment rapidly before. Sorry.. I guess my solution is for "You can also think this question such a way that how many non-equivalent colorings are there to color 24 square on a cube whose each faces have 4 squares." Right ?

Comment: @Aaron Now , iwant to also know the solution of the original one  ,i.e "How many non-equivalent configuration of 2×2×2 Rubik cube with 6 distinct colors are there?

" using Polya. runway44 gave a symetric group formula for that , but i do not know how to write it for Polya

Comment: From googling "symmetry group 2x2x2 rubik's cube" a top search result is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328498/what-are-the-symmetries-of-a-colored-rubiks-cube